# Regex expression with space does not compatible minify javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex

```
/(NaN| {2}|^$)/.test(a)
```

It work perfectly in developer mode. In production mode, javascript would be minified, so the white space has been removed, the regex would be

```
/(NaN|{2}|^$)/.test(a) => wrong
```

How do I remain correct above regex with minify javascript?

Comment: Try using `\s` to match a whitspace char `(NaN|\s{2}|^$)`

Comment: You really need to replace the minifer. It is broken. It shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: @RoToRa Can not. It is minifier of framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match a space using a regex escape like

```
\x20
\u0020
```

See a demo below:

```js
const a = "-  -";
console.log(/(NaN| {2}|^$)/.test(a));
console.log(/(NaN|\x20{2}|^$)/.test(a));
console.log(/(NaN|\u0020{2}|^$)/.test(a));
```